# Bundling .JS resources for IOS Simulation

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

In my app, I have support for multiple languages.
Each languages ownsa .js files which contains one single object with every 'displayable string'.

The system totally works on desktop (chrome or safari) but on mobile it does not at all. 
With alerts I found that whenever i was reaching for fields inside my language objects, it was not working.

Form that I guess my .js files are not bundled in my build when I Simulate on IOS via Sencha Architect.

Would someone help me do the job correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hand edit your app.json file so it look like this, architect doesn't do it itself.

```
"js": [
        {
            "path": "touch/sencha-touch.js",
            "x-bootstrap": true
        },
        {
            "path": "app.js",
            "bundle": true,  
            "update": "delta"
        },
        {
            "path": "PATH/TO/FILE.JS"
        }
    ],
```